# Bind XOFF and XON to a single terminal shortcut

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

To free space for custom keyboard shortcuts, I want to bind both terminal flow control characters to a single shortcut (e.g. make `Ctrl+S` send `XOFF` by default, but if terminal is already frozen, send `XON` instead).

Is it possible?

Comment: It's not the **terminal**, but the *terminal driver* which would have to be altered.  Try your luck with kernel.org :-)